# Save and open an Excel file from blob

Tags: javascript, arrays, blob, filesaver.js

I save the file but when I open the Excel file it says that the file is invalid.

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ23I.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2FqV.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiTUK.png)

[error message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvd6p.png)

```
const getReportInExelFile = () => {
  axios
    .post(
      'test', {
        filters: [{
          comparison: 'eq',
          fieldName: 'client_id',
          fieldValue: 29384
        }, ],
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      }
    )
    .then(({
      data
    }) => {
      console.log('data', data);

      let blob = new Blob([data], {
        type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
      });
      FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'CASES.xlsx');
    });
};
```

Comment: Share your codes instead of pictures!

Comment: @HibritUsta done.

Comment: Isn't the data already a blob? is `FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'CASES.xlsx');` not working?

Comment: @Daantje Comes to me byteArray, and based on this, I want to save the file in excel format and open. But now, i don't open excel file because he is invalid :(